# AVAudioPlayer Loses "Playing" Status

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer that needs to continue in the background.

Audio is set as the background mode in the plist & this runs on launch:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
[[RootController shared].view becomeFirstResponder];

AVAudioSession* session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setDelegate: self];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];
[session setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder { return YES; }
```

## The Problem

Occasionally the AVAudioPlayer gets in this strange state where:

- It's playing, but the play icon in the status bar disappears
- If I pause then play, the icon shows up for maybe a second, then disappears
- *Here's the kicker* - if I call `setCurrentTime` while playing, the play icon shows & stays

I've sunk about 20 hours into this & would love any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Description of the Bug

If you are *playing* an `AVAudioPlayer` then you *create* an `AVPlayer`, the playing icon will disappear. Apparently `AVPlayer` immediately takes precedence & since it is not playing yet the play icon disappears from the status bar.

This causes some serious issues:

1. If the app is in the background, iOS will shut down your AVAudioPlayer within 5 seconds (because it doesn't realize you're playing audio)
2. The iOS remote shows a play button even though audio is playing
3. The play icon is not showing in the status bar

## The Workaround

First off, if you don't have to use `AVPlayer`, then don't. I use it because I need to play a remote MP3 without downloading it first. I used to use this [AudioStreamer](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) class but gave up because it pops up an alert when the stream becomes disconnected along with a few other bugs that I couldn't fix.

So if you're stuck with AVPlayer, there's only one way to re-connect playing status with your `AVAudioPlayer`. **If you call `setCurrentTime` on the `AVAudioPlayer` then it will magically re-associate itself as the current player for the app**. So you'll need to call it after any `AVPlayer` is initialized and anytime you resume playback on your `AVAudioPlayer`.

I decided to subclass AVAudioPlayer so I could register it in a global list (when it is initialized) and unregister it when it is deallocated.  I also overrode the play method so that any calls to resume playback would also call setCurrentTime.  Then I subclassed AVPlayer so that any time one is initialized, all active AVAudioPlayers call setCurrentTime on themselves.  Last thing - you'll have to call `setCurrentTime` after a short, maybe 1 second, delay or else it will have no effect.

No kidding, this is the result of nearly 40 hours of troubleshooting.